# <apex:selectRadio> how to avoid multiple selection on radio button?

Tags: radio-button, salesforce

How to avoid multiple selection on radio button , i have used apex:repeat and repeat value is bounded to the controller's wrapper class but when i select radio button it allows multiple selection.

below is my code.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!availableSlosts}" var="as" id="eventlistId">
                        <tr>
                            <td><apex:selectRadio value="{!as.selectedEvent}">
                                     <apex:selectOptions value="{!as.lstRadioValue}"/>
                                </apex:selectRadio> 
                            </td> 
                            <td>{!as.availDate}</td>

                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>
```

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

radio buttons by nature exhibit the one selected only behavior. But you can did that by HTML and js. [Code sample here](http://www.eltoro.it/ArticleViewer?id=a07A000000NPRidIAH)

Answer (score 0):

> {!as.availDate}
>
> ```
>                     </tr>
>                 </apex:repeat>
> ```

Should be smth like

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!as.selectedEvent}">

<apex:repeat value="{!availableSlosts}" var="as" id="eventlistId">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                     <apex:selectOptions value="{!as.lstRadioValue}"/>

                            </td> 
                            <td>{!as.availDate}</td>

                        </tr>
                    </apex:repeat>

</apex:selectRadio>
```

But in this case I don't know what you will put into value atribute for selectRadio tag.

Comment: Hi Chiz/Shimshon Korits,
I have Added java script to deselect multiple Radio button and its working fine in MoZilla but does not work in Google chrome, below i smy javascript Code.

function deselect(selectObj) {
  var gettable= document.getElementById('filteredtabledataId');
  //alert(gettable);
  var radios = gettable.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for(i=0; i<radios.length; i++ ) {
      if(radios[i] != selectObj) {
             radios[i].checked = false;
      }
  }
 }